# Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface is not instantiable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working on a Laravel package, trying to inject "Illuminate\Validation\Factory" to __construct():

```
namespace Extensions\Tpp\Forms;


   use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as ValidatorInstance;
   use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as Validator;

   abstract class FormValidator {

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    protected $validator;

    /**
     * @var ValidatorInstance
     */
    protected $validation;

    function __construct(Validator $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }
```

But got following error:

```
    Illuminate \ Container \ BindingResolutionException
Target [Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface] is not instantiable.
```

I understand it means Laravel doesn't know which implementation of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface is. My question is why in normal Laravel application Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface can be bound, however in a Laravel package, it's not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why in normal Laravel application
>   Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface can be bound

It is because `Laravel` exclusively uses `Symfony` components and the `Validator` class has dependencies on following `Symfony` components (check the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`) along with other `Illuminate` components:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
```

You will be ab;e to use this (Remove the `use` statements):

```
function __construct(\Validator $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately by doing that, we lose the point of dependency injection. \Validator is same as Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator, I could do \Validator::make in my class without dependency injection at all.

Comment: `Unfortunately by doing that, we lose the point of dependency injection` How, you are still using a dependency injection in your constructor.

Comment: Also, if you directly want to use the underlying class instead of  `Facade` then you may also use `App::make('validator')` and you should not try to make instance of that by your self, ask the `App/IoC` but if you really want to do this by your self then check the `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider` to find out it's dependencies. I think you are missing something.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think what I will do as this article suggested: http://atrauzzi.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/moving-away-from-laravel-facades.html